# scriptcam will not initialize

Tags: javascript, jquery, webcam

I have setup my account on scriptcam, but can't get camera to load. I've created a test page to just get the video player up, and that won't work. I can't even get the errors to load, so I suspect that it's something to do with the scriptcam.js files not even being loaded? See below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1" />
    <title>iseYoo video test</title>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="scriptcam.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#webcam").scriptcam({ 
                onError: oopsError,
                showDebug: true
            });
        });
        function oopsError(errorId,errorMsg) {
            alert(errorMsg);
        }
        function showCurrentVersion() {
            alert($.scriptcam.version());
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="webcam"></div>
</body>
</html>
```